Multithreaded list comprehension in python is not faster compare to non threaded version
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

words = [...]  # List of ~100 words
dictionary = { # ~20K items
    'word1': 0.12,
    'word2': 0.32,
    'word3': 0.24,
    # more words...
}

def get_word_frequency(word):
    return (word, dictionary[word]) if word in dictionary else None

def search_words(words):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(get_word_frequency, words))
    return {word: freq for word, freq in results if freq is not None}

result = search_words(words)

The above code is taking almost the same time as normal list comprehension.
result = [w for w in words if w in dictionary.keys()]

Here I'm just showing a single dictionary as an example, in real case I do have near about 200 dictionaries loaded from a single json file. Sets performs way better than list but I'm not sure how can I implement a Set based comprehension in the above case.

The overhead in creating and maintaining threads far outweighs the processing complexity of your get_word_frequency function. Multithreading is not appropriate here

There are two main issues here:
First of all, don't expect multithreading to speed up anything in Python that is CPU bound.  All your threads run in a single process, and Python has a global lock that prevents more than one thread from running at a time.  The appropriate time to use multithreading is when your code is doing a lot of IO or networking, and one thread can run while another thread is working for external results.
The other issue, with both multithreading and multiprocessing, is that they have a cost to them.  Each call out to a thread or process has a cost, and each value returned has a cost. You will only win when the cost of setting up the computation is small compared to the computation you are performing in the thread.  In your code, the computation you are performing is miniscule.

result = [w for w in words if w in dictionary.keys()]
Here you're evaluating dictionary.keys() every iteration. This can cause problems. With low iterations wouldn't be a problem, but if words is long, can cause real problems.
I think that the best solution is to declare it as a variable:
keys = dictionary.keys()
result = [w for w in words if w in keys]

Here we are declaring the variable once, so it doesn't do it every iteration.
That should be the problem, let me know if this is correct.
